# Crystal Reports 2010 not showing all fields from a complex object

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm having some trouble populating a report with a complex object. I'm using .NET objects only, no database involved. Below is my class structure:

```
public int Year { get; set; }
public List<Schedule> { get; set; }
```

The schedule class itself has a number of decimal properties a string property for Name.

When I add this class to my report, the only available field for reporting is Year. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off separating this class into two separate ones. Using the same property on both classes and linking them in Crystal Reports is like joining two tables on a key.